# set RewriteBase dynamically based on the url

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, config

I have two php web apps that want to access using the same domain but based on the URL and what I have done so far I moved the files to the Linux server and there is a root folder of public_HTML and there two folders for app and CMS in the root folder I want to access the app and the CMS based on the URL for example if the Url is the domain.com it should open the CMS and if it's domain.com/* it should open the app.
I have something like this conf in htaccess it's working but it adds the **/app** and **/landing** after the url which I don't want that:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Set the base depending on the condition
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.domin\.sk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /landing/ [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.domin\.sk$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^landing/ /app%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# Handle trailing slash for the dating app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^ /app/%1 [R=301,L]
```

and I'm think of something like this conf but it's wrong and has error:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Set the base depending on the condition
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.domin\.sk$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ - [E=BASE:/landing]
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.domin\.sk$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$/* - [E=BASE:/app]

    RewriteBase %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

if anyone has experience with this and knows how to implement it let me know and save my day.
I know my conf is wrong and has an issue and it's to demonstrate what I want to achieve please don't mind updating or rewriting it entirely.

Thank you in advance

Comment: _"if the Url is the domain.com it should open the CMS and if it's domain.com/* it should open the app"_ - surely your CMS will need to request more than just one  single resource, so there will be other `domain.com/*` requests that are part of your CMS, and not of your app ...? Not sure how exactly this is supposed to work, can you please clarify?

Comment: I solved this issue but as you mentioned faced other issues with routing of app and CSS and as you said there are other requests like ajax and pages and other stuff also need to be managed which seems not able to it easily with access other than using subdir or subdomain